# How to access all the data in the API call

Tags: html, angular

```js
getNames(): Observable<bookmodel[]> {
  const endpoints = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=xxxxxxxx';
  return this.http.get(endpoints).pipe(
        map(this.extractData));
 }
```

```html
<h1 class="uk-flex uk-flex-center">Top Books{{bestsellers_date}}</h1>
<hr class="uk-divider-icon">
<div class="uk-child-width-1-5@s uk-grid-match" uk-grid>
    <div *ngFor="let name of names;  let i = index">
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-hover uk-card-body">
            <h3 class="uk-card-title">{{name.title}}</h3>
            <img style="height:250px;" src="{{name.book_image}}"><br/><br/>
            <span>Summary: {{name.description || ' NA' |characters:150}}</span><br />
            <hr class="uk-divider-icon">
            <span>Author {{name.author}}</span>
            <br/>
            <br/>Best Sellers Rank {{name.rank}}
            <br />
            <span>Weeks on List {{name.weeks_on_list}}</span>
            <div class="uk-card-footer">
                <span><a  class="uk-button uk-button-primary" href="{{name.amazon_product_url}}">Buy On Amazon</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Okay so the code above makes a call to the api and the api returns an object with nested arrays in order to get the infomation I want Ive put defined the data as data.results.books but theres data that I want to access in the data.results Ive tryed just taking the .books part out but the the NGFOR doesn't work with objects is there a way to store or even get the data in data.results and how would I store it

Comment: we would need to have the structure of bookmodel in order to make any sense of this

Comment: Why don't you return `results` and do the `ngFor` on `results.books`?

Comment: This worked thank you

Answer (score 2):

#### service.ts

```
getNames(): Observable<bookmodel[]> {
  const endpoints = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=7W3E72BGAxGLOHlX9Oe2GQSOtCtRJXAt';
  return this.http.get<bookmodel[]>(endpoints);
 }
```

#### component.ts

```
this.service.getNames().subscribe(names =>  this.names = names);
```

#### HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let name of names;  let i = index"> 
......
</div>
```

If you are not subscribing it use `async` pipe in html

```
<div *ngFor="let name of names | async;  let i = index"> 
    ......
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the `*ngFor` with an async pipe. You need to use `async` pipe because httpClient always returns Observable.

`<div *ngFor="let name of names | async;  let i = index"></div>`

Also update the `getNames` and remove the `.pipe` from there

```
getNames(): Observable<bookmodel[]> {
  const endpoints = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=7W3E72BGAxGLOHlX9Oe2GQSOtCtRJXAt';
  return this.http.get<bookmodel[]>(endpoints);
 }
```